# Xgboost h2o error on WIndows OS?

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o, xgboost

I tried to run xgboost on my local machine with Windows OS. But the following error :

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

java.lang.AssertionError: Unregistered algorithm xgboost
```

here is my code sample :

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(enable_assertions = TRUE)
localH2O=h2o.init(nthreads = 8)

train.h2o <- h2o.importFile("train.csv")
test.h2o <- h2o.importFile("test.csv")

# Number of CV folds (to generate level-one data for stacking)
nfolds <- 5

y <- get_index(train.h2o,"loss")
x <- setdiff(1:length(train.h2o), y)
x=h2o.colnames(train.h2o[,x])
y=h2o.colnames(train.h2o[,y])


my_xgb1 <- h2o.xgboost(x = x,
                       y = y,
                       training_frame = train.h2o,
                       ntrees = 50,
                       max_depth = 3,
                       min_rows = 2,
                       learn_rate = 0.2,
                       nfolds = nfolds,
                       fold_assignment = "Modulo",
                       keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                       seed = 1)
```

when I run it, I get the following error :

> ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Server Error (url =
>   http://localhost:54321/3/ModelBuilders/xgboost)
>
> java.lang.AssertionError  [1] "java.lang.AssertionError: Unregistered
>   algorithm xgboost"
>   [2] "    hex.ModelBuilder.make(ModelBuilder.java:149)"
>   [3] "
>   water.api.ModelBuildersHandler.fetch(ModelBuildersHandler.java:35)"
>   [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
>
> ....

I found here that xgboost for h2o work on some specific dev environments.

**MY QUESTION is:** how can I make it work on Windows OS ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

H2o xgboost is not currently supported in Windows.

Please see the attached screenshot from the latest docs page for h2o xgboost.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can vote for this feature here on github:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/issues/517

Comment: The link is about GPU support. Is that a requirement for xgboost on h2o?

Answer (score 0):

**XGBoost** is not supported on **Windows**.

> The list of limitations include:
>
> - XGBoost is not supported on **Windows**.
> - The list of supported platforms includes: Linux or OS X

When I met same issue I open my **COLAB** account and I try there. It did work for me.